# Can I provide a "Null" value for a xacro macro parameter?

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a .urdf.xacro file where a particular xacro macro has been defined with a few parameters including - "mesh". When I instantiate this particular macro in another file, I wish to leave out the "mesh" parameter and instead define a shape (like a rectangular box) of my own.

Is this possible at all?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71890/can-i-provide-a-%22null%22-value-for-a-xacro-macro-parameter?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The xacro converter seemed to be quite literally to me, but you could look at it's source.

Or you could remove mesh/shape from that macro and make two macros extending the base macro for both mesh and shape.

And `mesh=""` won't work?

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-08-12**:
I will look into the source, thanks! I tried mesh =" " but that didn't work because it searched for the ".stl" file (no name extension). I will check if modifying the xacro works or not. Thanks again!